# Mask touch gestures - android

Tags: android, viewgroup

OK lets make this basic, I have three `pages`(`viewgroups`) which I can scroll through like the home screen. On one of the `pages` is a gallery. Now the problem is any swipes on the gallery case the `pages` to change to. Is it possible to restrict trouch gestures to a certain part of the viewgroup?

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, only that I had buttons in a table layout. Overriding the viewgroup's dispatchTouchEvent() made it easy to switch between pages. The problem is that the button's do not receive clicks anymore.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, So i guess I should override dispatchtouchevent() and redirect the motionevents to the gallery only not the viewgroup.